# Simulating Arrays in Marie

Tags: arrays, assembly, marie

I'm tinkering around with the MARIE assembly language, but I can't find a way to simulate array functionality. I'm trying to write a program to find the dot product of two vectors (arrays) and I can't figure out how to get an arbitrary list of numbers saved, and then a second one after that.

I actually consulted an actual textbook that features MARIE and didn't find anything on it.

Comment: Since MARIE doesn't seem to have indirect addressing, you will probably need to write self modifying code.

Comment: @Jester I'm not sure what you mean by self-modifying code.I figured that I would definitely have to do some extra coding to simulate the concept of an array... I tried to find a way to add to an address (you know, to go from one item to another) but I couldn't find anything that would allow me to do that....

Comment: Yeah, me neither. That's why I figured to use self modifying code, that updates the address in the instruction so you can have  pointer indirection.